# How to come back to the start prompt after else?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I would like the else part of the following if-statement to make that prompt pop up again. In other words, I want the prompt to come back if user writes something other than "yes" or "no".

```
var str = prompt("Do you want to come in?").toLowerCase();
if (srt === "yes"){
    alert("cool.");
}
else if (str === "no"){
    alert("goodbye.");
}
else {
    var str = prompt("Do you want to come in?").toLowerCase();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you have made a typo mistake

```
function showPromptBox(msg) {

    var str = prompt(msg) ? prompt(msg).toLowerCase() : "" ;
    if (str === "yes") {
        alert("cool.");
    } else if (str === "no") {
        alert("goodbye.");
    } else {
        showPromptBox(msg);
    }

}

showPromptBox("Do you want to come in?");
```

**Second way**

```
var str = prompt("Do you want to come in?") ? prompt("Do you want to come in?").toLowerCase() : "";
if (str === "yes") {// typo mistake
    alert("cool.");
}
else if (str === "no") {
    alert("goodbye.");
}
else {
    var str = prompt("Do you want to come in?") ? prompt("Do you want to come in?").toLowerCase() : "";
}
```

Comment: Thank your for your help @NarendraChouhan. Does `var str = prompt(msg) ? prompt(msg).toLowerCase() : undefined;` illustrate the ternary operator ?:? What does `: undefined` exactly do?

Comment: you can keep the empty string i,e `" "` rather then undefined let me modify it

Comment: code gets to break, the prompt doesn't have any value so for that, I have to used the ternary operator to if there is null value then it will be `" "` string so that code won't break

Comment: That was very clear. Is that the most common role of the `?:` operator?

Comment: What if the code would start with `var str = prompt(msg) ? : "" ;` only? Is `prompt(msg).toLowerCase()` compulsory?

Comment: yes is necessary, `?:` is   just like if condition that whether there is a value or not

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a simple recursive function.

```js
function showPrompt(msg) {
  var str = prompt(msg).toLowerCase();
  if (str === "yes") {
    alert("cool.");
  } else if (str === "no") {
    alert("goodbye.");
  } else {
    showPrompt(msg);
  }
}

showPrompt("Do you want to come in?");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create three separate function each for handling different responsibility.

```js
// this function will only show prompt
function showPrompt() {
  return prompt("Do you want to come in?").toLowerCase();
}
// this function will be called to only show alert
function showAlert(alertText) {
  alert(alertText);
}
// this function will be called to show alert and then depending on the 
// value it will show alert or will call prompt
function callAlert() {
  const val = showPrompt();
  if (val === 'yes') {
    showAlert('cool');
  } else if (val === 'no') {
    showAlert('goodbye')
  } else {
    callAlert();
  }
}
callAlert();
```